# How can I remove only the 'minimise' button from stage components and how can I customize the components in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx-2

How can I remove only the 'minimise' button from stage components and how can I customize them in JavaFX?
I am using Netbeans 7.1.2 and created a simple JavaFX app. I have the object of stage named primaryStage. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately JavaFX 2.2 doesn't yet provide API to manipulate system window buttons.

Although you can achieve that by removing system controls with

```
     primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED)
```

and providing your own ones to maximize, close, etc.

You can find an example in standard sample named Ensemble which follows described approach:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/samples/index.html

Comment: I already tried it once.It makes all the windows button removed. I just only want to remove the 'Minimise' button. Any other options to attain the feature?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this

```
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();        
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);

    primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.DECORATED);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

The key is setResizable(false)