# How to create a JavaFX dialog?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx-2, javafx

I need to create a dialog in JavaFX. I know that I can make the Stage behave like a dialog by modifying modal, owner and resizable properties.

But how do I hide the "minimize" and "maximize" buttons from the Stage window? Typical dialogs only have the "close" button.

Comment: Maybe this [thread][1] will solve your problem.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12912638/how-can-i-remove-only-the-minimise-button-from-stage-components-and-how-can-i

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Under Windows 7, initializing to [StageStyle.UTILITY](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/StageStyle.html#UTILITY) before you show the window will create a window with only a close button and no minimize or maximize button:

```
Stage dialog = new Stage();
dialog.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(new Text(25, 25, "Hello World!")));
dialog.setScene(scene);
dialog.show();
```

If you would like a complete set of basic JavaFX dialogs I would recommend the [JavaFX UI sandbox dialogs](http://fxexperience.com/2012/10/announcing-the-javafx-ui-controls-sandbox/).

The JavaFX UI Sandbox was not created by me and is not hosted on my site (source is hosted by Oracle).  I [requested Oracle to document the sandbox dialog API](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-27567).  If you like, you may vote for or comment on the request.

[Makery's blog](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-2-dialogs) has some minimal 3rd party documentation of the sandbox dialogs, including basic usage examples as well as a backport of the dialog portion to JavaFX 2.2.

**Update**

The JavaFX UI Sandbox has been superseded by the [ControlsFX project](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/).

**Update**

[Java 8u40 will include JavaFX dialogs](http://fxexperience.com/2014/06/bringing-dialogs-to-javafx/) built into the core platform APIs.  You can try an [early access release of Java8u40](https://jdk8.java.net).  The relevant class is javafx.scene.control.Dialog and it's related subclasses such as javafx.scene.control.Alert (the Alert class is for showing standard dialogs which are similar to Swing's JOptionPane class - so you don't need to use JOptionPane to get out of the box standard dialog functionality).

[Makery wrote a new blog tutorial for dialog functionality provided in Java 8u40](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/).

**Related Questions**

- [How to create and show common dialog (Error, Warning, Confirmation) in JavaFX 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309981/how-to-create-and-show-common-dialog-error-warning-confirmation-in-javafx-2)

Comment: @jewelsea, went to your site. Is there a download link for the code just for the popups or jar for the library? I downloaded the entire project which is quite large - just need the dialog stuff. Also examples of how to use your dialogs would help greatly

Comment: Updated answer to address your comment Anil.

Comment: I created a backport of JavaFX 8.40 Dialogs to JDK7: https://github.com/BertelSpA/openjfx-dialogs-jdk7

Comment: Thanks for keeping this answer up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try my approach to the custom dialog window for Java FX 8. Both: source code with practical use example, and runnable demo are available in the link below:

https://github.com/bluevoxel/ChooseStage

And that how it's looks like:

[image]