# Show Alert JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

When the alert is opened, this minimized the main window, displays the alert, when I close the alert, returns to the main window.
It is possible that the alert is displayed above the main window ??
Thanks.

```
Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
alert.setTitle("Information Dialog");
alert.setTitle("Information Dialog");
alert.setHeaderText("Look, an Information Dialog");


alert.show();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168064/how-to-create-a-javafx-dialog) ?

Comment: I don't see this behavior; it simply shows the Alert in front of the existing window. Can you create a simple [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the behavior you are describing?

Comment: Hi @James_D, This problem occurs when stage.setFullScreen (true);, Thanks.

Comment: alert.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
alert.initOwner(primaryStage);

Answer (score 2):

Please set the owner of the alert box like below

```
alert.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
alert.initOwner(primaryStage);
```

Cheers